# CorePlot - CPTTimeFormatter gives me the same time for every element of my bar plot

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, graph, core-plot

I have a graph using Core-plot (CPTBarPlot) and I want to show days on the X axis, a different day for each bar in order.  I have tried to set up CPTTimeFormatter as follows where x is my x axis.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
    NSDate *refDate = [NSDate date];

    timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
    x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
```

Inside of numbersForPlot I am returning a set of numbers representing the elapsed seconds, and since I want to have sequential days it looks like     0,
    86400,
    172800,
    259200,
    345600,
    432000,
    518400
etc.

I expected the X axis labels in this case to be sequential list of dates starting at refDate and going up by the number of seconds in numbersForPlot. Instead all I see is the same date repeating over and over for every bar on the x axis. Can anybody explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I might be able to fix it? thanks.

EDIT: this is what my numbersForPlot function looks like inside my datasource:

```
-(NSArray *)numbersForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange
{   
    NSArray *nums = nil;

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            nums = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:indexRange.length];
            for ( NSUInteger i = indexRange.location; i < NSMaxRange(indexRange); i++ ) {
                [(NSMutableArray *)nums addObject :[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i*secondsPerDay]];
            }
            NSLog(@"NUMS  = %@",nums);

            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            nums = [stepsPerDay objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:indexRange]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return nums;
}
```

The relevant part is case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation which returns n array of values which I believe is correct...

NUMS  = (
    0,
    86400,
    172800,
    259200,
    345600,
    432000,
    518400
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to set

```
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInteger(secondsPerDay);
```

This bug was confusing me though because everything looked perfect minus the x labels repeating so it was hard to see that anything was wrong. Once I set the interval length to the proper value the X axis labels correctly showed the dates that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatter code looks correct. Make sure the datasource is returning the correct x-values, e.g., 0, 86400, 172800, etc. for values one day apart.

Comment: This is what my numbersForPlot function looks like inside the datasource... oops I can't post it in this comment box because it is too long.

Comment: I have updated the original question to show the datasource. Does it look correct?